# How do I shift all the elements within a nested python list downward?

Tags: python, nested-lists

we have a 4x4 board containing empty values, and 1s

```
board = [
[" "," ","1"," "],
[" "," ","1"," "],
["1","1"," "," "],
["1"," "," ","1"]
]
```

now we want to the final result to look like this?

```
gravity(board) == [
[" "," "," "," "],
[" "," "," "," "],
["1"," ","1"," "],
["1","1","1","1"]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea: For each column, you run from the bottom to top. If you found an "1", then assign it to the bottom.

```
for j in range(len(board[0])):
    cnt = len(board)-1
    for i in range(len(board)-1, -1, -1):
        if (board[i][j]=='1'):
            board[i][j]=''
            board[cnt][j]='1'
            cnt -= 1
```

Result:

```
[[' ' ' ' '' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' '' ' ']
 ['1' '' '1' ' ']
 ['1' '1' '1' '1']]
```